# permission issue while installing a npm package

Tags: npm, permissions, ubuntu-18.04, adminlte

While I'm installing [admin-lte@3.0.5](https://github.com/ColorlibHQ/AdminLTE) I get the following error:

> ```
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins'.
> ```

Help me how to fix the permission.

**Full Error Log:**

> ```
> ubuntu@ip-XXX-XX-X-XX:/var/www/acceptance$ sudo npm install
> npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
> npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
> npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
> npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
> npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
> npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues.
>                     Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
>
> > admin-lte@3.0.5 install /var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte
> > npm run plugins
>
>
> > admin-lte@3.0.5 plugins /var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte
> > node build/npm/Publish.js -v
>
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/bootstrap'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/fontawesome-free'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/fontawesome-free'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/overlayScrollbars'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/overlayScrollbars'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/bootstrap-slider'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/bootstrap-colorpicker'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/bootstrap-colorpicker'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/moment'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/datatables-bs4'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/datatables-bs4'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/datatables-autofill'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/datatables-autofill'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/datatables-autofill'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/datatables-buttons'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/datatables-buttons'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/datatables-buttons'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/datatables-colreorder'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/datatables-colreorder'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/datatables-colreorder'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/datatables-fixedcolumns'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/datatables-fixedcolumns'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/datatables-fixedcolumns'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/datatables-fixedheader'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/datatables-fixedheader'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/datatables-fixedheader'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/datatables-keytable'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/datatables-keytable'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/datatables-keytable'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/datatables-responsive'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/datatables-responsive'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/datatables-responsive'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/datatables-rowgroup'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/datatables-rowgroup'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/datatables-rowgroup'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/datatables-rowreorder'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/datatables-rowreorder'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/datatables-rowreorder'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/datatables-scroller'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/datatables-scroller'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/datatables-scroller'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/datatables-select'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/datatables-select'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/datatables-select'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/jsgrid'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/flag-icon-css'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins/flag-icon-css'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins'
> Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/var/www/acceptance/node_modules/admin-lte/plugins'
>
> ┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
> │                 npm update check failed                                                                                             
> │           Try running with sudo or get access            
> │           to the local update config store via           
> │ sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) /home/ubuntu/.config 
> └──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
> ```

**package.json**

```json
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --disable-host-check --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "cross-env": "^7.0",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.13",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.0",
        "sass": "^1.15.2",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "admin-lte": "^3.0.5"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Run `sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) /home/ubuntu/.config` on the command line in your project.

Comment: not working.`sudo chown -R acceptance:$(id -gn acceptance) /home/ubuntu/.config` Remember acceptance is owner of the directory.

Comment: sudo chown -R acceptance:$(id -gn acceptance) /var/www/acceptance